# If you as much as (go/come) near the building we're going to

Tags: idiomatic-language

Quick question. Is it necessary to include "go" or "come" here for this to work or is it natural without?

If you as much as (go/come) near the building we're going to kill the hostages.

Comment: Okay. How about: "If you near the building we're going to..."?

Comment: Unusual and unnatural.

Comment: The word **near** can be used as a verb (**to near the end**). So it's grammatically correct to talk about **(to) near the building** but it's most unlikely in context. If I came across it in a text, I would wonder what the author was try to tell me about the character. People don't say **Don't near me**. They say: **Don't come near me**.

Comment: to near something is not to come/go near something

Comment: I suppose "to near" something is an English verb, but it's not used often in such a context. It wouldn't be strictly wrong to use it the way you use it (it tends to be used in the context of travel, and particularly nautical or aerial travel). "We're nearing the [air]port, Captain!" The example given above (as something to avoid), "Don't near me" suggests that the listener shouldn't navigate their vessel or aircraft towards the speaker. Even as a metaphor it sounds a bit unnatural. The main point is that "if you so much as ...", when used as a threat or a warning, needs a verb.

Answer (score 1):

We usually use [***so** much as* rather than ***as** much as*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If%20you%20as%20much%20as%2CIf%20you%20so%20much%20as%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) in such contexts...

[image]

...but there's nothing actually *wrong* with the version as cited by OP - it's just the less common stylistic choice.

Essentially, ***so/as much as*** is an optional *intensifier* in such contexts. A common alternative is *If you **dare** move I'll kill you*. Or we can add ***even*** before the forbidden act and put heavy stress on the verb: *If you even **move** I'll kill you*.

As ever, the choice between ***come** near* and ***go** near* simply depends on whether the speaker is currently ***at*** the location. It's very uncommon for that rule to be broken by native speakers, but [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97033/very-confused-go-home-or-come-home), [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118031/come-home-or-go-home), and [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/258171/go-back-home-vs-come-back-home) are some earlier ELL questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

You must have one of “come” or “go near”  to be correct.

It is an action that will cause the hostage to be killed. The coming or going.