# he hasn't been home much lately

Tags: present-perfect

A wife complains to her friends about her husband,

> He hasn't been home much lately.

Can I change it to these two sentences?

> He hasn't come home much lately.

> He hasn't gone home much lately.

Comment: "come home" and "go home"  are not interchangeable. Does [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/258174/2818) explain it well enough to you? And as to tell you if one or the other would match "he hasn't been", you'd need to give more context, although at first glance I can't see how one or the other could. Also: can you feel the difference between : "He hasn't been home much lately" and "he hasn't often been to Britain" which have a different meaning of the verb "be".

Comment: As a British English speaker I would say "He hasn't been **at** home much lately."

Comment: Thank you all very much.

Comment: @None: now I see the difference. Be home here means be at home. If the wife wants to indicate her husband came back home only once a week, what should she say? Can she say *He hasn't come back home much lately*?

Comment: If the husband is working somewhere too far away for him to live at home, but he used to come home at regular intervals until recently, she might well say that.